# replace raw data in stream (ffmpeg)

Tags: video, replace, ffmpeg, binary

I've got a video file from which I have extracted a data stream. Something like this

> ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -map 0:3 -f rawvideo output.raw

I have made some modifications to the output.raw file, and now would like to replace the data in the original 0:3 stream with my modified version, while keeping all the metadata of the stream the same. I have been googling around with no success. Maybe I am not using the right wording.

Thanks

Comment: “codec copy” and “rawvideo” are opposites. Which one you really want to modify?

Comment: @szatmary I think rawvideo is what I need. At least if I delete "-codec copy" the output stays the same (what I need), but if I remove "-f rawvideo" I get nothing. As you can see, this was initially written by somebody else, so so far my progress has been through trial and error. Thanks

Comment: Show the complete output of `ffmpeg -i input.mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my initial approach was wrong. I was trying to get the raw data from the source video file, but apparently there is no way to mux the modified stream back into the file, with ffmpeg. So I had to use "-codec copy" instead to save the whole stream.

> ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -codec copy -map 0:3 to_modify.mp4

Make my changes there, and merge all the streams in a new file like so:

> ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -i modified.mp4 -c copy -map_metadata 0 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 1:0 output.mp4

I hope this makes sense